# Does the recursive .htaccess rule affects subdomains pointing to subdirectories?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, recursion, apache2

Suppose I have a site `example.com` which points to the root directory of my hosting account and it has a .htaccess file in that directory. Say I have an other domain `stuff.example.com` which points to the same hosting account, but to a subdirectory of it, not to the root directory, and that subdirectory also has a .htaccess file in it.

If I visit `stuff.example.com` then will its .htaccess file be affected by the .htaccess settings of the root directory? Or htaccess search starts from the directory where the domain points to, so in this case the htaccess file in the parent directory is not taken into account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surprisingly the Apache docs don't ever explicitly answer this, as far as I can tell.  But the [htaccess tutorial](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html#when) gives the example that if a file is requested from /www/htdocs/example, then Apache looks for the following .htaccess files:

```
/.htaccess
/www/.htaccess
/www/htdocs/.htaccess
/www/htdocs/example/.htaccess
```

which presumably leads outside of the DocumentRoot.  So it seems that the answer to your question is yes, Apache will read all .htaccess files all the way up to /.

Answer (score 1):

> will its .htaccess file be affected by the .htaccess settings of the root directory?

Yes. Where your web root is doesn't matter.

Comment: Is this the same for addon domains that have their root folder in a subdirectory? Will they also be affected by the root .htaccess?